# ¿como hago para que el sonido deje de sonar hasta que se levante el dedo del touch?

Tags: java, android

como va? alguien podria decirme que tendria que hacer para que el sonido deje de sonar hasta que deje presionar el boton? 
Intente con el motion.event actiondown y actionup pero suena el sonido completo, pero solo quiero que se reproduzca hasta que el usuario suelte el boton del touch?.. no se si tiene que ver el sonido (sample) que esta en formato .ogg ... y tengo entendido que con el metodo media player es para sonidos largos y soundpool para los cortos...

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton imTecla29,imTecla30;

private SoundPool soundPool;

private int sonTecla29, sonTecla30;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //ORIENTACION

   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    imTecla29=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.tecla1);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        soundPool =new SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(5).build();
    }else {
        soundPool= new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);

    }

    sonTecla29=soundPool.load(this, R.raw.acor29,1);

     imTecla29.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                soundPool.play(sonTecla29,1,1,0,0,0);

            }else if(motionEvent.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                soundPool.stop();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia es que la reproduccion lo manejes con AudioManager para que puedas manipular utilizar los eventos segun tu interes.

```
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener
```

Si suceden varias reproducciones y estas suceden parcialmente o permanentemente tambien debes obligatoriamente trabajar con el focus para redirigir la reproduccion y poner en pausa las que no son de interes hasta que el evento termine.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
  AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener =
  new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
  if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
    // Permanent loss of audio focus
    // Pause playback immediately
    mediaController.getTransportControls().pause();
    // Wait 30 seconds before stopping playback
    mHandler.postDelayed(mDelayedStopRunnable,
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
  }
  else if (focusChange == AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) {
    // Pause playback
  } else if (focusChange == AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {
    // Lower the volume, keep playing
  } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
    // Your app has been granted audio focus again
    // Raise volume to normal, restart playback if necessary
  }
}
};
```

revisa este link de android developer: 
[AndroidDeveloper. Focus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus.html)

Answer (score -1):

El problema por el cual no deja de sonar es que estas definiendo la reproducción de 5 Streams al mismo tiempo:

```
 soundPool= new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
```

Si defines solo un Stream debe funcionar sin problema:

```
 soundPool= new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.